# how to check what incorrect password as attempted

Tags: authentication, pam, logs

In `/var/logs/auth.log` I can see the unsuccessful login attempts. They are like lines below:

```
Oct 16 05:04:02 myMachine unix_chkpwd[15793]: password check failed for user (user1).
```

Now is there a way to see what password was tried exactly ? Is that information logged anywhere ?

I want to see the incorrect password that was attempted.

Answer (score 4):

No, and that would be a HUGE security issue. Last time I checked anyone with a login or physical access to the machine can access this log.

I'm an untalented hacker and I want to elevate my rights on the machine: I would simply search the log for similar unsuccessful login attempt. Then I would be able to greatly improve the speed of a brute force attack.

What is it exactly you want to achieve? Some guru might be able to find a witty workaround for you.

Comment: This guy fiddle with pam source code and then use his custom version to log the passwords as well: http://www.adeptus-mechanicus.com/codex/logsshp/logsshp.html. This is a stupid idea IMO.